# Referencing nested generic parameter in another

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function that works with ID'd `item` objects and an interface for collections of same `items`

```
interface Item {
    id: string
}

interface Collectable<T extends Item> extends Object {
    entities: { [key: string]: T },
    ids: string[]
};
```

I'd like to implement a function signature for adding an item to a collection of items. For this I need to enforce that the Item type and the Item type nested inside the Collectable interface are the same

```
export function addToCollection<C extends Collectable<T>> (collection: C, item: T): C
```

Allowing for something like this

```
interface Apple extends Item {};
const apple: Apple = { id: 1, color: 'red' }
const collection: Collectable<Apple> = { entities: {}, ids: [] }
return addToCollection(collection, apple);
// { entities: { 1: { id: 1, color: 'red }}, ids: [1] }
```

Problem is I can't find a way to do this, without also specifying nested type T as a type parameter

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `T` to the function type parameter list:

```
export function addToCollection<T extends Item, C extends Collectable<T>> (collection: C, item: T): C {
    return null;
}

declare var c: Collectable<{ id: string, n: string }>;
declare var d: { id: string, n: string };
addToCollection(c, d); // works T and C are inferred correctly
```

This will work well with derived types as well:

```
interface Apple extends Item {
    name : string;
    size: number;
}
interface AppleCollectable extends   Collectable<Apple>{
    bushelSize: number

}
declare var apples: AppleCollectable;
declare var a: Apple;
addToCollection(apples, a); // Works correctly, returns AppleCollectable
declare var applesBase: Collectable<Apple>;
addToCollection(applesBase, a); // returns Collectable<Apple>
```

**Edit**

One problem with the implementation above is that the following code compiles:

```
addToCollection(apples, { id: "" })
```

There is a problem with the way typescript infers generic parameters, it can't infer `T` based on another type parameter to which it is dependent (In this case `C extends Collectable<T>`). It can check it but it can't infer it.

One option would be to lock down who `T` is, and take a `Collectable<T>`

```
export function addToCollection<T extends Item>(collection: Collectable<T>) {
    return function (item: T): Collectable<T> {
        return null; // Actual code
    };
}
addToCollection(apples)(a); // Works
addToCollection(apples)({ id: "" }) // Does not work
```

The problem with this approach is that the return type is `Collectable<T>` not `AppleCollectable`. The ugly work around for this is to specify the parameter twice, once as `Collection<T>` and once as `C`, but this is definitely not an ideal solution:

```
export function addToCollection<T extends Item, C extends Collectable<T>>(collection: Collectable<T>, dummy: C) {
    return function (item: T): C {
        return null;
    };
}
addToCollection(apples, apples)({ id: "" }) // returns AppleCollectable
```

The simplest solution would however be to add the `add` function to the interface:

```
interface Collectable<T extends Item> extends Object {
    entities: { [key: string]: T },
    ids: string[]
    addToCollection(item: T): this;
};
interface AppleCollectable extends Collectable<Apple> {
    bushelSize: number
}
apples.addToCollection(a).bushelSize // addToCollection return AppleCollectable 
apples.addToCollection({ id: "" }) // does not work
```

Comment: But this way I can still call the `addToCollection` with a type that conforms to `Item`, but not `Apple`

Comment: @Tarlen yes this is the behaviour, `T` is independently constrained to extend `Item` and since `Collection<T>` imposes this constraint on it's generic parameter it would be a compiler error not to specify it on the function `T` parameter

Comment: Does that mean I'll always have to call it like `addToCollection<Apple, AppleCollection>(...)` if I want to allow for what im describing?

Comment: @Tarlen added sample in the answer to address this, all works as expected without the need to be explicit about generic parameter types

Comment: So yes the types are inferred correctly, but you're still able to for example, pass an object with just the ID, and not the remaining apple fields to the apple collection? Ideally the compiler would warn if you tried to pass anything other than an Apple

Comment: @Tarlen Unfortunately that is true, because of the way structural type compatibility works `Collectable<Item>`  is assignable from `Collectable<Apple>` , to the compiler decides that `T` can be `Item` to satisfy both parameters. I have a solution to this but it implies changing things a bit, I will update the answer shortly

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep the objects plain without any functions defined on them so the above won't work. Thanks for taking your time to help me out though, much appreciated